# remove duplicates in LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I am a beginner in java. I have written the following code to find duplicates and remove them in a LinkedList but I am getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. please help. Thanks in advance.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class LinkedListEx 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(2);
        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(4);
        l1.add(1);
        System.out.println(l1);
        int i = l1.size();
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            for(int k=j+1;k<i;k++)
            {
                if(l1.get(j) == l1.get(k)){
                    l1.remove(k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: the problem is int k=j+1 in the second loop check if that is valid to the list on then get into that loop.

Comment: Can you use alternate data structures?

Comment: @StackFlowed - no - its `j<i` - should be `j<i-1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `get(int)` on a `LinkedList`. It's fine on an `ArrayList`, but a `LinkedList` has to traverse the list to find the n'th element.

Use a `Set` to remember which values have already been seen, and iterate the list using an `Iterator`.

```
LinkedList<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
l1.add(1);
l1.add(2);
l1.add(1);
l1.add(4);
l1.add(1);
System.out.println(l1);

HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = l1.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer value = iter.next();
    if (! set.add(value))
        iter.remove();
}
System.out.println(l1);
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 1, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This code is amazing ... It took some time for me to understand that set doesn't take duplicates... This website is teaching me a lot :-)

Comment: What happens if i convert LinkedList to a set?? will the duplicates be removed automatically??

Comment: @pavan Yes. That is what the answer from Puce relies on. He simply adds all the elements from the list to a set that retains order (`LinkedHashSet`), then copies the (now distinct) values back to a list. Note that a `HashSet` would work too, but it wouldn't retain original order, and a `TreeSet` would actually sort the values.

Answer (score 3):

Use Iterator to traverse through list when you are going to modify the list.

You are removing the items from list, which reduces the size of list but your loop still runs for initial size of list.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I didn't realize that.

Comment: So is there no other way to do it using the for loops??

Comment: you can do. You're doing it. But that is not the correct way.

Comment: Using Iterator also you can use for loop. Something like - 
`for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = yourList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Integer item = iterator.next();
    ....
}`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
...

Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
// either
list = new LinkedList<>(set);

// or
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

With Java SE 8 you could also use:

```
list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Or if it doesn't have to be a LinkedList (not very often needed in my experience):

```
list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice and concise, but it doesn't remove the duplicates from the original list, it replaces the list. Depending on actual need, your answer may be perfect or useless. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas you can use clear() and addAll() if you prefer the original list object...

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @Puce This is concise and the easiest way to remove duplicates without using any logic. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `for loop` should be more like this and also by updating your variable `i`:

```
int i = l1.size();
for(int j=0;j<i-1;j++) {
       for(int k=j+1;k<i;k++) {
           if(l1.get(j) == l1.get(k)) {
               l1.remove(k);
               i--; //Updated size
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: sorry but that didn't work I'm getting the same exception